# make a pwd type function in c

Tags: c, linux

I'm pulling my hair out here.  Its been about 1.5 years since I've done any c programming so bear with me.

I need to make a function in c that does what the pwd function does in linux.  I have a struct of nodes that represent a folder.  Each one has a pointer back to its parent so it should be pretty easy but I'm dying here.  I thought I could just keep using strcat to append the name of a nodes parent to the path name.  But, even if I was able to get this to work I would be left with a list that is in reverse, which is fine I guess.  I could at least deal with that.  But if I'm in directory c whose parent is b whose parent is a whose parent is root I should be able to use pwd to output the string "/a/b/c".  I'm stuck.  Any ideas?  When I try to use strcat I get segmentation faults up the ying yang.

```
void pwd( ){  

    char *thePath;
    NODE *nodePtr;
    nodePtr = cwd;

    while( nodePtr != root ){

    }
    printf("%s\n", thePath);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you allocating enough memory for the results of your `strcat` operations?  Can you how some more complete code and ask specific questions about the problems you're having?

Comment: is `*thePath` allocated? how do you `strcat` the strings?

Comment: Can't you call `getcwd` ? Or look inside its source code? Anyway you should reallocate and concatenate strings (and later free them appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is print out the path, this should be pretty easy with recursion.

```
void pwd_recurse (NODE *nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr == root)
    {
         return;
    }
    pwd_recurse(nodePtr->parent);
    printf("/%s",nodePtr->name);
}

void pwd()
{
    ///however you get the nodePtr;
    pwd_recurse(nodePtr);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This nicely sidesteps having to deal with memory allocations (though it does mean if you have a degenerate filesystem with loops (insert obligatory XKCD cartoon here), you'll have a stackoverflow, which is arguable better than an infinite loop.)

Comment: This works fine.  I guess I'm just a managed memory guy living in a c world.  I hate having to remember all this memory allocation stuff.  Does this ever get easier?

Comment: Vanilla C?  Not really, other than knowing where to look and what not.  C++?  Possibly.  Note that there's a school of thought that suffering through C memory management is useful (like eating your vegetables) in that it gives you a better understanding of things like Schmiel the Painter's algorithm issues.